# Exponential trigonometric function zeroes

Tags: calculus, roots

How would I find the zero of this exponential function:

$f(x)= sin e^x$

After i set the equation to zero, what do i do?
Does this involve finding the derivatives?

Comment: No derivative. We want $e^x=n\pi$.

Comment: it must be $$e^x=k\cdot \pi$$ with $$k>0$$ and $k$ is an integer

Comment: why does pi come though instead of sin?

Comment: Because   sin (z)=0 iff  z /pi is an integer. Therefore sin (exp (x) )=0 iff (exp (x) )/pi is an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
0 = \sin(e^x) \Rightarrow \\
k \, \pi = e^x \quad \Rightarrow \\
x = \ln(k \, \pi)
$$
where $k \in \mathbb{N}$. I only considered real solutions.